# Text in nested flexbox doesn't truncate, min-width doesn't work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've been trying for hours to get text truncation working in a flexbox (mostly with Bootstrap 5) with no luck. Been reading all over about needing to use `min-with: 0` on the parent div, but I think I've tried every combination of that and can't get it to work.

I also read about `align-items-center` stretching the text and needing `width: 100%` but I can't get that to work either.

The code snippet should demonstrate the issue, please ignore the broken layout.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Edit: Trying to avoid defining width as it needs to be responsive

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="userManagmentSearch" />
      <span class="input-group-text" id="userManagmentSearch">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
        </svg>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <img style="width: 24px" class="me-3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/24x24.png" alt="User Avatar" />
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div>
            <span class="fw-bold">admin</span>
            <br />
            <span class="text-muted text-truncate">
              admin@email.comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center flex-wrap">
        <span class="badge bg-danger mx-1 my-1">Admin</span>
        <span class="badge bg-success mx-1 my-1">Moderator</span>
        <span class="badge bg-secondary mx-1 my-1">User</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">moderator</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">moderatoranduser</li>
</ul>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"
                aria-describedby="userManagmentSearch" />
            <span class="input-group-text" id="userManagmentSearch">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                    class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
                </svg>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <img style="width: 24px" class="me-3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/24x24.png"
                    alt="User Avatar" />
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div>
                        <span class="fw-bold">admin</span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 150px;">
                            admin@email.comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center flex-wrap">
                <span class="badge bg-danger mx-1 my-1">Admin</span>
                <span class="badge bg-success mx-1 my-1">Moderator</span>
                <span class="badge bg-secondary mx-1 my-1">User</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">moderator</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">moderatoranduser</li>
</ul>
```

use this `bootstrap-5` code for your solution

Comment: are there any other changes appart form the `max-width: 150px` on the `text-trucate` span?

was also trying to avoid defining a width or max-width as it needs to be responsive

Comment: you have to use max-width for text-truncate it's compulsory otherwise it will take full width and you can not truncate.

Answer (score 0):

Change Some Class & Added CSS `.flex-fill`

CSS

```
.flex-fill{min-width:1px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex flex-fill">
        <img style="width: 24px" class="me-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/24x24.png" alt="User Avatar" />
        <div class="d-flex flex-fill align-items-center">
          <div class="d-flex text-truncate">
            <span class="fw-bold me-3">admin</span>
            <span class="text-muted flex-fill text-truncate">
 admin@email.comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
        <span class="badge bg-danger mx-1 my-1">Admin</span>
        <span class="badge bg-success mx-1 my-1">Moderator</span>
        <span class="badge bg-secondary mx-1 my-1">User</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.flex-fill{min-width:1px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="userManagmentSearch" />
      <span class="input-group-text" id="userManagmentSearch">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
        </svg>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex flex-fill">
        <img style="width: 24px" class="me-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/24x24.png" alt="User Avatar" />
        <div class="d-flex flex-fill align-items-center">
          <div class="d-flex text-truncate">
            <span class="fw-bold me-3">admin</span>
            <span class="text-muted flex-fill text-truncate">
 admin@email.comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
        <span class="badge bg-danger mx-1 my-1">Admin</span>
        <span class="badge bg-success mx-1 my-1">Moderator</span>
        <span class="badge bg-secondary mx-1 my-1">User</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">moderator</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">moderatoranduser</li>
</ul>;
```

Comment: this works but adding the `d-flex` to the `text-truncate` div changes the layout

Comment: saying that i did remove the `d-flex` and it worked for a while but it just stopped working